# Continuous vector field on open domain, uniformly continuous argument

Tags: real-analysis

I'm going through a proof at the moment where the following is stated.

For a continuous vector field $V: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^k$ where $\Omega$ is an open set we can, given $\varepsilon > 0$ choose $\delta > 0$ so that the following is satisfied for a specific $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$

$$\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k \ | \ \lVert x-y \rVert < \delta\} \subseteq \Omega$$
$$\lVert x-y \rVert < \delta \implies \lVert V(x)-V(y) \rVert < \varepsilon$$

The second condition appears to be some form of uniform continuity for vector fields. I'm not entirely sure if that is simply the definition of continuity for a vector field and if it is then I have no quarrel with the statements made.

I do think that this is some variation of the theorem of continuous functions that states that every continuous function on a closed and bounded domain is uniformly continuous. However, as you can see, the domain isnt closed, so I cannot understand how that this has been reasoned. Hope someone can clarify the argument.

Comment: Is there a missing quantifier for $x$ in the first condition?

Comment: That is not how my textbook defines a set but I can put one in if it makes it more understandable.

Comment: Is there a fixed $x$ for the first condition?  Or is it those $y$ such that the inequality holds for all $x$?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I see where the confusion arises. Yes it is for a fixed $x$. Let me edit that.

Comment: And I now understand that this isnt uniform continuity since it is specific $x$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have fixed a single $x$, the second statement is just ordinary continuity at the point $x$, rather than uniform continuity throughout the region.